# CakePHP named paramaters in FireFox Causing issues

Tags: firefox, url, cakephp, encoding, named-parameters

We have a cakephp app running on 2.0 and we seem to be having some encoding issues with Firefox.

The URL we are accessing is /newcms/core/users/index/conditions[User][group_id]:6 to apply a filter in out cms system.

In everything but FireFox we get the following on the request object

```
[params] => Array
        (
            [plugin] => core
            [controller] => users
            [action] => newcms_index
            [named] => Array
                (
                    [conditions] => Array
                        (
                            [User] => Array
                                (
                                    [group_id] => 6
                                )

                        )

                )

            [pass] => Array
                (
                )

            [prefix] => newcms
        )
```

Which is correct and everything works fine, if we goto the same URL in FireFox we get

```
[params] => Array
        (
            [plugin] => core
            [controller] => users
            [action] => newcms_index
            [named] => Array
                (
                    [conditions%5BUser%5D%5Bgroup_id%5D] => 6
                )

            [pass] => Array
                (
                )

            [prefix] => newcms
        )
```

I have tried URL encoding the named condition value but with no luck..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you making the square braces as part of the url parameters? Of course it is getting URL encoded. Why not use named parameters?

Comment: @Barry, he *is* using named parameters, but he's trying to make them nested. I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: @bfavaretto thats not true, he is passing them as part of the URL directly. BAD.

Comment: @bfavaretto Nested named parameters were added in Cake 2, so yes it is possible. And although I agree that passing conditions in the url is a bad idea, it does appear like this may be a bug.

Comment: @Barry:  bfavaretto is correct - he IS using a named parameter - hence the something:something in the URL.

Comment: Right sorry - I mis-typed. I meant he is verbosely trying to pass the model/field structure as part of the named parameter. That is not going to work.

Comment: @Barry: It does work though, as it should with all browsers except FF. I also don't see why it shouldn't work...there is no readon the square brackets shouldn't come through and be decoded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a bit of digging and playing around the latest version of cake in GitHub has fixed this FF issue (https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/e6905b44c3d4512b6989c59a1489bc983d88bcdc).

There is nothing incorrect about passing square brackets in the URI it was just an issue with the way FF encoded them differently than the other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not a great idea to be using brackets and an array structure in your URL.

Why not just use something like this?:

```
/newcms/core/users/index/user_group:6
```

Then process the data in the controller.

Comment: We cant really do that as it is for a cms that created filters dynamically. In non-firefox browsers it does all the parsing in the core and we get the names paramater back as an array which is ideal. If there is no way in FF we may just have to use something like pipes to replace the square brackets and then decode that in the app controller...not ideal though...stupid FF